# Apache and php-fpm - user isolation

Tags: php, apache

I have set up a default Apache + php-fpm and the setup below works. Is it good enough for running hosting on or is there modules I'm missing?

I'm just trying to learn how it all works together and how to create user separation/isolation - so that files created on a vhost on server is owned by that user and not apache/www (system users). I also want to be able to have several php-fpm pools.

The way I have set it up, kind of works by having one php-fpm pool per user. All files managed by this vhost is owned by the user I have put into the fpm-pool-config.  But I would need to create a lot of ports and one /etc/php-fpm.d/test99com.conf per user.

Is the setup below safe? I notice cPanel have user-section in their vhost and I only have it in my php-fpm.

I would also know how to limit the vhost by memory: For instance max 256 MB.

Note that I only intend to host PHP-software (no cgi/perl).

Apache httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "/home/test99/public_html"
ServerName test99.com

 <FilesMatch \.php$>
  #SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
  SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9001"
 </FilesMatch>

<Directory "/home/test99/public_html">
  allow from all
  Options None
  Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

php-fpm.d/test99no.conf

```
; Start a new pool named 'www'.
; the variable $pool can we used in any directive and will be replaced by     the
; pool name ('www' here)
[test99]
user = test99
group = test99
listen = 127.0.0.1:9001
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
```

Comment: cPanel use `mod_itk`